# What are the consequences of excessive drinking?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Throughout the world of Azeroth, there are a plethora of alcoholic beverages available.

Upon consuming a few strong ones, or a bunch of weak ones, I have become intoxicated to the point where I can barely fly/walk/ride straight, and cannot see much on the screen as everything has become blurry.

I have heard that you could reach a point of puking, slurred speech, etc.

Are there other effects? Such as casting wrong spells, missing your target more often, or perhaps passing out or achieving some other form of paralysis?

Are there any long term effects?

So basically, what are the effects of excessive drinking?

Comment: Broken friendships, troubled relationships, unhealthy dependencies, and bankruptcy are just some of the consequences. Be aware of how you might be hurting those around you...

Comment: Stack Exchange question titles... every time...

Comment: @nyuszika7h It's a special property only found in Arqade. It's both a blessing and a curse.

Comment: I actually have such a question in my head at the moment that I might ask on a bored moment.

Comment: @Pharap Actually, [rpg.se] had one recently-ish asking why one shouldn't kick people.

Comment: @michaelb958 Good lord it's contagious! Quick, lock away your daughters!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are many effects that occur but I wouldn't classify any of them as "Fatal". The things that will happen:

**Negative effects:**

- Your screen goes blurry
- You can't really walk straight anymore (swimming and flying can be really tough)
- If you say something in chat "S" will occasionally become "SH" and sometimes a "...hic!" is added randomly.
- The level of NPCs is displayed as 5 levels lower (the real level still remains the same though).
- You can get a debuff "Totally Smashed" that will cause you to vomit. You are stunned during this.

**Positive(?) effects:**

- You can get an achievement for falling 65 yards if you're drunk during the brewfest.
- Yay let's get smashed in an MMO!

Your Drunk status will go away after some time or on-death.

Comment: I didn't know about the level adjustment, quite fun: is it a recent change, or has it always been around?

Comment: @Lohoris That has always been around. I remember getting caught out by it in Vanilla WoW.

Comment: Just for info, I'm pretty sure you can negate the majority of the graphical effects (blurry screen) by changing certain video options. Can't remember what exactly they are though.

Comment: It's Full Screen Glow in the video options menu. You can also do /console ffxglow 0 to turn it off and use a 1 to turn it back on.

Comment: I actually like flying while drunk ingame. It's amusing to see how the intoxication level of the rider can affect the motion of the mount.

Comment: The blurry screen will occasionally give me a mild headache IRL. When I saw this question, that was the first thing I thought of in terms of consequences. Kinda funny, since drinking IRL often results in a headache as well.

Comment: "Your Drunk status will go away after some time or on-death" Cue loads of drunkards trying to commit suicide in an attempt to sober-up.

Answer (score 10):

Drinking makes you walk and and run in staggering lines, the screen becomes blurry, your typed speech is slurred and punctuated with hiccups, your toon will puke, and **the levels of hostile (confirmed), neutral (confirmed) and friendly (unconfirmed) mobs will appear lower**.

Comment: You're missing a noun. Hostile, neutral and friendly what?

Comment: There's an opportunity here for Pandaren in WoW to be a drunken master! The more drunk you get, the better your evasion, dexterity, and strength. After a few hours though, you should get a bad headache and get sleepy.